# How to play two swf files in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

hai i want play two swf files in my action script project.In this two files one swf file works on the detection face in front of the system.Other swf plays the flv file.when face is detected player must be stooped if not player must be plays the flv file.

I know how to load the swf file but i cant handle the functionality regarding  starting and stoping player.

the snippet of code shows how can i load external swf file .and i will explain each line of code in comments

```
    public function videos(view:Sprite)
    {
        this.box = view;//IT GETS Sprite object from other class because of               need to display the player also.
        request = new URLRequest("Untitled-1.swf");
        currentSWF=new MovieClip();


        loader= new Loader();
        loader.load(request);

        box.addChild(loader);
        currentSWF = MovieClip(loader.content);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadComplete);
        //addChild(loader);
        currentSWF.gotoAndPlay(1);//when i put this line of code in  comments it plays the external swf also. 


    }
```

I hope u understand my doubt .can any one explain how to handle my things .i am new to this action script.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Loaded files automatically play, unless you tell them explicitely not to. You’ll have to listen to the `Event.INIT` event, and stop the movie there:

```
loader.AddEventListener(Event.INIT, initLoader);

function initLoader (event:Event)
{
    MovieClip(event.currentTarget.content).stop();
}
```

This will stop the movie before it is attached to the stage, and before it starts playing—so it won’t do that unless you start it again.

Note that you shouldn’t access `loader.content` in any way before the `INIT` or `COMPLETE` events, as it’s very likely that the content isn’t loaded then. As such you should put all your manipulating actions into the `COMPLETE` event:

```
box.addChild(loader);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

function loadComplete (event:Event)
{
    // Now it’s safe to access the `content` member:
    currentSWF = MovieClip(loader.content);

    // Of course this one would play the movie again, so you probably want
    // to call that later on a button click or something.
    currentSWF.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```